# How to put stuff into __init__(self): by giving parameter in variable?

Tags: python, class, oop

So, I am basically trying to write a code where i want to declare parameters during declaration some thing like:

```
class emp:
     def __init__(self,a,b):
          self.first_name=a
          self.last_name=b
Rohan=emp("Rohan","foo",age=12,nationality="Indian")
print(Rohan.age)
```

The following code yields the output:

```
TypeError: __ init __() got an unexpected keyword argument 'age'
```

What i want is:12

If possible can i aslo put default values where the following code yields

```
Jhonny=emp(age=,nationality='')

jhony.age=5
jhony.nationality="Indian"
```

Comment: So, why don't you just add those parameters to your class definition?

Comment: basically It's just for learning purposes, I was trying to solve a puzzle. I want to be able to take whatever parameter given by user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure that you want to do it this way, you can do the following:

```
class emp:
    def __init__(self, a, b, **kwargs):
        self.first_name = a
        self.last_name = b
        for key, val in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, val)
```

That said, it's not great practice to do so. I would agree that it would be better to put them as optional arguments in your `__init__` function.